# $P(X \cap Y) \ge P(X) + P(Y) - 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

So I've come across the following inequality for probability measures:

$$
P(X \cap Y) \ge P(X) + P(Y) - 1
$$

I'm trying to work out why it should be true. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

I have the following:

$$
P(X \cap Y) = P(X) +P(Y) - P(X \cup Y) \le P(X) +P(Y) - 1
$$

This seems to suggest that the inequality is the wrong way round. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: if $a \leq b$, then $-a \geq -b$.

Comment: Duh. Is there a `{being-stupid}` tag? I think I deserve it for this question.

Comment: I see no need for $-a \leq -b$, $P(X \cup Y) \leq 1$ and $P(X \cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(X \cap Y)$ will do it.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker because I couldn't accept an answer at the time. There is a minimum time limit before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(X\cup Y)\leq 1$. Hence $-P(X\cup Y)\geq -1$.

Answer (score 1):

All the pieces are already on this page in one place or another.  Here's how I would put them together: $1 \geq P(X \cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X\cap Y)$.  So, $1-P(X) - P(Y) \geq -P(X\cap Y)$. Then you use what Michael and Hurkly observed (multiply my negative one on each side and flip the inequality) to find that this implies $P(X) + P(Y) - 1 \leq P(X\cap Y)$, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I convinced myself of the truth of the inequality as follows: If $X$ and $Y$ are both big ($>0.5$) then they must overlap. So, $P(X)+P(Y)-1$ measures the size of the forced overlap. (obviously it will be less than 0 when no overlap is forced.)